# Como girar o servo motor usando Arduíno e um botão? Qual seria a função?

Tags: arduino

Gostaria de uma ajuda para programar o servo motor com Arduíno com um botão. Como posso controlar o tempo de rotação com timestamp? Preciso fazer o servo motor girar de -90º para 180º. Obrigada!

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo servo;
#define pinServo A1

void servolala(){
  static unsigned long timestamp;
  static byte stateS = 0;
  static int angle = 0;
  unsigned long timer;

  timestamp = millis();
  for(angle=0; angle>-90; angle--){
    servo.write()
    }
  switch(state){
    case 1:
    //continue
  }

}
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinServo, INPUT_PULLUP);
  servo.attach(6);
}
void loop(){
  servolala();
}"
```

Comment: O `servo.write` leva a posição que o servo tem de ficar em graus (0-180). Veja o [exemplo do Servo na documentação](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sweep), assim como a [própria biblioteca](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Servo) caso queria consultar alguma das funções

Comment: Como é que controlo o tempo dentro da função for que controla a posicao do servo?

Comment: Controlar o tempo é só usar `delay()` colocando o tempo em milisegundos, que servirá como tempo de espera entre cada rotação. O exemplo que citei atrás tem delays para que a rotação seja temporizada.

Comment: E se eu nao utilizar o delay? e sim timestamps

Comment: Também dá mas é como se fosse espera ativa